# Facing issue while saving manipulated document object from node to elasticsearch

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-client

I am converting image data into vectors using transformer JS inside my node application then I am initialising that vectors to a document coming from telegram API and saving that document to elastic Search DB.
I am able to see all data of that document in elastic search but the vector data field is not visible in that document. Please help me to save that data properly in elastic Search DB.
Here is the way of saving that document in elastic search db.

```
  let { image_embeds } = await visionModel(imageInputs); // Vision Model from transformer JS
  TGApiMessageList[0].media.photo["imageEmbedding"] = image_embeds;
  SaveDataToElasticSearchDB(TGApiMessageList[0]);// Its saving all data except TGApiMessageList[0].media.photo.imageEmbedding
```

Note : imageEmbedding key value pair is absent in that document.
Please help me to solve this issue.